# A python class constructor error

Tags: python, oop, class, constructor

i have this line in my main.py:

```
import classes
info = classes.information(a, b, c)
```

and this class and constructor in classes.py

```
class information:
    #constructor:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
```

and it says this constructor takes no arguments (3 given)

did i do anything wrong here?

Comment: Note that [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) recommends `CapWords` for class names.

Comment: Also, when you get an exception, please post the whole stack trace, not just the message - it makes it far easier to track down the problem.

Comment: You probably did do something wrong, but it is impossible to tell what exactly from the information you've given us so far.

Comment: With the code you post I don't get any error.

Comment: Did you give values to `a`, `b`, and `c`? Doing it just how you explained, I got a `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`. You would get those for `b` and `c` as well, except that an error was raised before then.

Answer (score 0):

`classes.information(a, b, c)` **isn't** calling the `classes` constructor `classes.__init__()`. Rather it's calling what looks like something called a classmethod of the `classes` class itself.

This *might* be what you want (can't say for sure without more code and/or information):

```
import classes
classes_obj = classes(a, b, c)  # create instance of classes (call constructor)
info = classes_obj.information()  # call method of that instance
```